# Como puedo hacer que me aparezcan seleccionados los checkbox que guarde en mi base

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravelcollective

en esta parte los muestro

```
<h3>Lista de permisos</h3>



              <div class="form-group">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        @foreach( $permissions as $permission)
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    {{Form::checkbox('permissions[]',$permission->id,null)}}
                                    {{$permission->name}}
                                    <em>({{$permission->description ?:'Sin descripcion'}})</em>
                                </label>

                            </li>
                        @endforeach

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

**este es mi controlador**

```
public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
    {
//        actualizar usuario
        $role->update($request->all());

//        actualizar roles
        $role->permissions()->sync($request->get('roles'));

        return redirect()->route('roles.edit',$role->id)
            ->with('info','Rol actualizado con exito');
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se sabe si el permiso debería estar checked o no? ¿alguna propiedad de $permission?

Comment: bueno hasta ahorita no tengo ninguna propiedad bueno entiendo mucho

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:
siempre y cuando tu propiedad se llame `checked` o algo referente

```
<h3>Lista de permisos</h3>
<div class="form-group">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        @foreach( $permissions as $permission)
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input id="{{ $permission->id }}" name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $permission->id }}"
                    @if($permissions->checked)
                        checked=checked
                    @endif
                    >{{$permission->name}}
                    <em>({{$permission->description ?:'Sin descripcion'}})</em>
                </label>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: creo que redacte mal la pregunta la pregunta en si es que cuando valla a la vista editar me aparezcan ya seleccionados para saber cuales habia guardado y seleccionar nuevos